# Huawei app doesn't show app gallery event its state released

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

Hello i have a problem.

We had published our app two days ago to your app gallery.

i can't see my app on huawei app gallery via my phone but i can see the app when i get in the web site of huawei app gallery.

also some phones which containts google play and huawei app gallery can show the app on huawei app gallery ( generally old phones )

- My phone is huawei-y6p
- My app gallery version is 11.1.1.304
- My Region is Turkey ( our app support turkey, i checked from developer
  console )
- My phone model is MED-LX9N
- EMUI Version is 10.1.0
- Android version 10

so what is the problem why can't i show my app on huawei app gallery via my phone ?

also if i click the market url of my app via my phone it opens my app on app gallery but the install button is disabled.

Can you help me about this issue, thank you very much.

Comment: Could you please provide your appid for further analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be you can install app on devices with GMS. So it looks like that you app has google libs and doesn't have Huawei libs and it's published in AppGallery in state, that allows to install app only for users with google services.

So you must upload version with Huawei services integrated as without them app can't work on devices without google services.

Answer (score 0):

Your Huawei Y6P (MED-LX9N) phone do not have Google Mobile Services/GMS (aka Google Play Services) but Huawei Mobile Services (HMS) only . Huawei phones released after May 2019 do not have GMS installed. The legacy Huawei phones have both GMS & HMS.

Most likely your app has strong dependency on GMS SDK and services and may negatively affect user experience so it was hidden from newer phones with HMS-only. It is available on legacy phones because those phones have GMS.

To make it available on HMS-only phone AppGallery, you need to integrate [HMS Core](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/) and replace the GMS dependency. You can use [HMS Toolkit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/huawei-toolkit/) to scan your project and convert it into HMS app, or a G+H app (GMS+HMS).

There are also several app release strategies, you can take a look:
[Multi-APK Version Release](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-multipleapk)
[Configuring GMS/HMS Restrictions in the Multi-APK Version Release Scenario](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/agc-gmshmsdependency)