# Many users who tell me that the (Install) button for my application is disabled at the Huawei App Gallery

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery-connect

The users keep telling me that they can't install the app because the App Gallery  is disabling the install button of my app

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately huawei dont have any tools to identify and remove the GMS dependencies from the project. WE ahve remove manually.
Once the app is published, it will be reviewed for the compatibility and if the app is compatible with all the devices, then it will be released to all users

Answer (score 0):

Yeah . I got the answer from
[Huawei app doesn't show app gallery event its state released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65708559/huawei-app-doesnt-show-app-gallery-event-its-state-released).

But is a pleasure to know that the problem is because GMS so now I have more info about the case, but please How can I remove the GMS from my application
my application is developed by react-native and I just released new apk and pushed to ur app gallery.
Should I remove all react-native google libs like firebase and so on ?
I have no time to release a version integrated with HMS now but for sure the next version will.
If there is away to remove the GMS and republish the apk with no HMS ?